# Locate saved game file

Tags: games

I am playing bygfoot football manager game in ubuntu 11.04. i saved the game and it saved my game in "homefolder/.bygfoot/saves" path. Now i want to play the same game on another computer. so how to find my saved game file, so that i can load that game in that computer and play. When i visit my home folder i am not able to see ".bygfoot" folder at all. How to access this? please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have it installed? Are you viewing hidden files?

Comment: yes i have the game installed through software center. i am not viewing hidden files. how to view hidden files?

Comment: Press Ctrl+H in nautilus (the file browser).

Comment: Thank you so much. such a simple thing to just select "show hidden files" in view on the menu bar. I was thinking it might be complex. but your suggestion directed me to finding the file. I was able to find it in my normal login itself. didnt have to use nautilus.

Comment: Press Ctrl+H in nautilus (the file browser). – nickguletskii.

Thank you for "nickguletskii".

The above help from "nickguletskii" helped me to view hidden files in my user account. I found the hidden files and the saved game files under the game folder. I didnt have to use nautilus. When I clicked "show hidden files" in the home folder the applications folders appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in nautilus (the file browser). – nickguletskii. Thank you for "nickguletskii". The above help from "nickguletskii" helped me to view hidden files in my user account. I found the hidden files and the saved game files under the game folder. I didnt have to use nautilus. When I clicked "show hidden files" in the home folder the applications folders appeared